# Order of bandpass / bandstop filter?

Tags: filter, active-filter, passive-filter

I am unsure if a bandpass with one zero at 0 Hz and two poles above would be called a first order or a second order filter. The amplitude is rising and falling with 20 dB / decade and the phase approaches +/- 90 degrees, which indicates a first order filter. But there are two poles.
Same for an equivalent bandstop: it has one pole and one zero.
Are these first order filters or a second order filters?

Comment: The order of a filter is equal to the number of active (so contributing) reactive elements in the filter. Make a plot of the filter response . *and the phase approaches +/- 90 degrees, which indicates a first order filter* No, I can design a higher order filter that does the same. There are phase equalization filters that have a nearly flat frequency response so the slope of the frequency response doesn't tell the complete story.

Comment: I guess you are referring to an allpass? Phase changes, group delay changes, but amplitude stays flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am unsure if a bandpass with one zero at 0 Hz and two poles above
>   would be called a first order or a second order filter.*

This picture might help: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/svf/Bode_Plots_Second_Order_Butterworth.html).

The orange line is the band-pass response of a 2nd order filter. It has slopes of 20 dB per decade. You might notice that if you rotated the low-pass response anticlockwise it would become the band-pass response. Similarly for the high-pass response.

> *the phase approaches +/- 90 degrees, which indicates a first order
>   filter.*

A first order filter would not have a 180 degree spread in the phase response - it would have a spread of only 90 degrees.